# Python Numpy Array Append with Blank Columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays, I am using the top row as column headers. Each array has the same columns except for 2 columns. arr2 will have a different C column as well as an additional column

How can I combine all of these columns into a single np array?

```
arr1 = [ ['A', 'B', 'C1'], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1] ]
arr2 = [ ['A', 'B', 'C2', 'C3'], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0] ]
a1 = np.array(arr1)
a2 = np.array(arr2)

b = np.append(a1, a2, axis=0)
print(b)

# Desired Result
# A B C1 C2 C3
# 1 1  0  -  -
# 0 1  1  -  -
# 0 1  -  0  1
# 0 0  -  1  0
```

Comment: What's supposed to be in the 'blank' columns?  A 2d `numpy` array has to have a value for each cell.  The only 'blank' integer is one that you choose to handle different, such as `-1`.  What are you going to do with this array?  That could determine whether an array is right structure or not.

Comment: I'm going to export this to csv for analysis. The blanks can be -1 or anything. The actual np arrays I have have floats and strings in the columns

Comment: It might be simpler if you opened a text file, and wrote your own formatted strings, one row at a time.

Comment: Try np.nan, it usually renders as 'blank'..

Comment: You need [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this. Doing it with NumPy will make you sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy arrays aren't great for handling data with named columns, which might contain different types. Instead, I would use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

arr1 = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1] ]
arr2 = [[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0] ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr1, columns=['A', 'B', 'C1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2, columns=['A', 'B', 'C2', 'C3'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)

df.to_csv('mydata.csv', index=False)
```

This results in a 'dataframe', a spreadsheet-like data structure. Jupyter Notebooks render these as follows:

[image: example of dataframe rendered in HTML]

You might notice there's an extra new column; this is the "index", which you can think of as row labels. You don't need it if you don't want it in your CSV, but if you carry on doing things in the dataframe, you might want to do `df = df.reset_index()` to relabel the rows in a more useful way.

If you want the dataframe back as a NumPy array, you can do `df.values` and away you go. It doesn't have the column names though.

Last thing: if you *really* want to stay in NumPy-land, then check out [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html), which give you another way to name the columns, essentially, in an array. Honestly, since `pandas` came along, I hardly ever see these in the wild.